# Change volume of noficiation with ringtone on vibrate

Tags: volume-control

I was wondering if it is possible in Android 4.4.2 to change the volume of the notifications while the ringtone is put on vibrate.

I'm using an *Samsung S4 mini* with the stock OS that was installed on it. The problem is, once I enable the volume of the ringtone, I can change the notifications volume independently. But once I put the ringtone on vibrate, the notifications volume gets disabled.

Comment: AFAIK, on stock, the notification sound will usually follow the ringer volume. I might be wrong though. In the meanwhile, could you mention your device model, and whether you're using stock/custom ROM?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention it, I'm using an Samsung S4 mini with the stock OS that was installed on it. The problem is, once I enable the volume of the ringtone, I can change the notifications volume independently. But once I put the ringtone on vibrate, the notifications volume gets disabled.

Comment: Consec, note you can always [edit] your post to include additional details – that makes them easier to detect, in the comments they might get lost (did that for you now). Apart from that, you might wish to check some helpers for [Volume control](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_settings#group_871), giving you better/easier access to those settings.